# Edit value of a html input form by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

my HTML code:

```
<form action="Generator.klx" method="post" onsubmit="genarate('hiddenField')">
   <input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" name="hidden" value=""/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

my JavaScript:

```
function genarate(hiddenField){
  var field = document.getElementById(hiddenField);
  field.value = "new Value";
 }
```

But it just didnot work :(. Can anybody tell me where I was wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly does not work? Value assignment? Form submit? Cooking coffee?

Comment: :), The Generator.klx can't receive the value of the hiddenField

Comment: @user552279: Mmmh... have you tried `field.setAttribute('value', "new Value");` instead of `field.value` ? (just guessing here ;))

Comment: @user: Are you saying that changing `field.value = "new Value";` to `field.setAttribute('value', "new Value");` and **changing nothing else** solved the problem? I find that *very* hard to believe, setting field values via the `value` property is bog standard and has been since 1995 or so. I've tried your code with IE6, IE9, Firefox 3.6, Chrome 10, Opera 11, and Safari 5. It works with `field.value = "new Value";`, full stop. You must have changed something else at the same time.

Comment: yes, i just change form .value to .setAttribute and it works fine :|

Comment: @user: Well, I'm glad you got it working, but with respect, I believe you must have changed something else at the same time or there's something else involved that isn't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code as quoted should be working, and does in my tests with a variety of browsers. (I've tried it locally, with a POSTed form, but you can also try it here: http://jsbin.com/ehoro4/1 I've changed the method to `GET` so you can see the result in the URL.)

My guess is that you have something *else* on the page with the `name` or `id` "hiddenField", other than just the hidden field you've quoted. If you change the name of the field to "fluglehorn" or something else that's (um) unlikely to be elsewhere on your page, it may well work. That's because the namespace used by `getElementById` is (sadly) quite crowded.

Alternately, are you sure that `genarate` is appearing at global scope? (E.g., it's outside of all other functions.) Because your `onsubmit` attribute requires that `genarate` be global. So this works:

```
<form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="genarate('hiddenField')">
   <input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" name="hidden" value=""/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
function genarate(hiddenField){
  var field = document.getElementById(hiddenField);
  field.value = "new Value";
}
</script>
```

but for example this would not:

```
<form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="genarate('hiddenField')">
   <input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" name="hidden" value=""/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
(function() { // Begin scoping function to avoid global symbols (not uncommon)
    function genarate(hiddenField){
      var field = document.getElementById(hiddenField);
      field.value = "new Value";
    }
})();
</script>
```

Also recommend using a debugger (there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) for not using client-side debuggers here in 2011) to set a breakpoint on the `genarate` function and walk through, to see what's going wrong.

Comment: possible common pitfall: order of declaration and initialization.

Comment: @Caspar: Agreed, although in his case, since he's using an `onsubmit` attribute, it won't get evaluated until the form is submitted, so as long as `genarate` is in the global scope, it'll get picked up even if defined after the form.

Comment: @Michael K: Thanks for the edit, but for future reference, when that happens it's usually because some jacka$$ has vandalized the most recent version of the JSBin. To fix it, one can point to a specific version (in this case, http://jsbin.com/ehoro4/1).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm new to the front-end side of stackoverflow and I was redirected to a vandalized page so I tried to clean it up. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

crud.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"  onfocus="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
<button type="button" onclick="myFun()">submit</button>
<button type="button" onclick="update()">update</button>
<br><br>
<p id="table"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript.js

```
var arr = [];
var index;
function myFun()
{
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
arr.push(name);
table();

}
function table(){
var text = "<table border=1><tr><th>username</th><th>action</th></tr>"
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
text+="<tr><td>"+arr[i]+"</td><td><button 
onclick=myDELE("+i+");>delete</button><button 
onclick=myEdit("+i+");>edit</button></td></tr>"
}
text+="</table>";
console.log(text);

document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = text;
tablehidden();
}

function myDELE(i)
{
var name = arr.splice(i,1);

// name.splice(i,1);
console.log(name);
table();
tablehidden();
}
function tablehidden(){
if (!arr.length) { document.getElementById('table').hidden=true; }
else{document.getElementById('table').hidden=false;}
}
function myEdit(i)
{
text = document.getElementById('name').value = arr[i];
         index = i;
}
function update(){
arr[index]=document.getElementById('name').value ;
table();
tablehidden();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.